# component of vue js is not showing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to use a component within my Laravel 5.5 project that I created but for some reason it is not shown.

I have tried to show messages using the method created, but I also do not get answers which makes me think that the component is not being loaded, I have enclosed everything inside the div with id app.

I've used npm update, and refreshed and erased the cache however it still does not work, what should I do?

this is my code:

Notification.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2">notificaciones
                    <span class="new badge">{{unreads.length}}</span>


                    <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
            <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["unreads", "userid"],
        created: function () {
            alert("test")
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            Echo.private('App.User.' + this.userid)
                .notification((notification) => {
                    console.log(notification.type);
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('notification', require('./components/Notification.vue').default);
Vue.component('test', require('./components/test.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        notification,
  }
});
```

my layout file

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

@section('htmlheader')
    @include('layouts.partials.htmlheader')
@show
<body >
<div id="app">


    @include('layouts.partials.mainheader')

    <div class="wrapper">


    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">

      <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
            @yield('main-content')

        </section><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->


    @include('layouts.partials.footer')
   @include('layouts.partials.modals')

</div><!-- ./wrapper -->
</div>
@section('scripts')
    @include('layouts.partials.scripts')
@show
@yield('pagescript')
</body>
</html>
```

here I try to show the component

mainheader.blade.php

```
    <!-- Dropdown Structure-->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="upperbody.html">Upper Body</a></li>
    <li><a href="lowerbody.html">Lower Body</a></li>
    <li><a href="core.html">Core</a></li>
    <li><a href="conditioning.html">Conditioning</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>


<nav>

    {{---Notifications ---}}

  <notification :userid="{{auth()->id()}}" :unreads="{{auth()->user()->unreadNotifications}}"></notification>

            {{---------------}}

            @section('sidebar')
             @if(Auth::check())
             @include('layouts.partials.sidebar_auth')
             @else
             @include('layouts.partials.sidebar')
             @endif
            @show            

        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you compiled the JS using Laravel-mix (or something else)? Also, do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I use npm run watch I haven't used it

Comment: no, I  don't have any error

Comment: You haven't used it??

Comment: I have not used laravel mix

Comment: npm run watch should be using Laravel mix. If you don't have any errors at all in your browser console or your terminal then the only other thing I would suggest is removing the `.default` from `require('./components/Notification.vue').default`.

Comment: I have deleted it, I have executed npm run watch again and nothing has happened, the strange thing is that the message that I have placed inside created () is not even displayed

Comment: Start by stripping out everything except the console.log (even the template).  that way you can know if it's the build process or not

Comment: it also seems like you might be missing this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo